# Can CGI program return control to popup window instead of parent screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perl, cgi

I have a simple test program, user clicks a button, a popup shows, user inputs name, submit, now is my problem: the cgi program prints "THANK YOU" to the main browser window, I want the "THANK YOU" goes to the popup window, and the main browser window remains unchanged.

HTML:

```
  1 <!DOCTYPE html>
  2 <html>
  3
  4 <head>
  5 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  6 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
  7 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  8 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  9 </head>
 10
 11 <body>
 12
 13 <div data-role="page">
 14   <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
 15     <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
 16     <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content">
 17     <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/eg.pl">
 18     <label for="fname">Write your name and click the button:</label>
 19     <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
 20     <input type="submit" value="Submit Button">
 21     </form>
 22     </div>
 23   </div>
 24 </div>
 25
 26 </body>
 27 </html>
```

CGI Perl program:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2
  3 use CGI;
  4 my $cgi = CGI->new();
  5 my $fname = $cgi->param("fname");
  6
  7 chomp ($fname);
  8
  9 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 10
 11 print "<body>";
 12
 13 print "THANK YOU!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem exactly, but you can use the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) attribute on the form tag to send the request to a popup window.

You'll need to name the window in the javascript that creates the popup, then use that name in the target attribute.